# latest updates for CSS and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

From where I can get latest updates for CSS and jQuery regularly? i.e. some feeds etc etc...

baljit

Comment: Please try and show that you tried to answer your own question, for example by indicating "I went to site x, but I'm not sure it is official" etc.   in this fashion you'll get better responses.

Answer (score 3):

The latest builds of jQuery can be found [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery).  Look at the Nightly Build if you're wanting something newer than the Current Release.

CSS is a specification and not code but you can follow the latest recommendations and drafts [here](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work).

If you use [Google AJAX Libraries API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#googleDotLoadVersioning) you can be sure to have the latest point release of a version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you mean by updating CSS, you don't really need to do anything.

As for jQuery, you can always grab the latest version off of their website, [jQuery.com](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Download_jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

You can pick your news sources from http://alltop.com:

- http://ajax.alltop.com/ for ajax
  related news,
- http://web-design.alltop.com/ for
  some css related stuff
- http://ria.alltop.com/ for rich
  internet app news

Answer (score 0):

twitter.com

Follow 'em... :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow http://jquery.com/. Also subscribe its rss feeds.

Answer (score 0):

doesn't have jquery, but [this is a good indicator for what the browsers support](http://a.deveria.com/caniuse/),  :D